# Visualize the bubblesort

Tags: reactjs, jsx, bubble-sort

i'm trying to understand better react and algorithms so i decided to implement a visual bubbleSort.

***Problem***

I'm able to generate a random array of numbers + sort the values and display them...but
I cannot figure how to make the swap animation between two elements.

***Code***

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './Chart.css';


class Chart extends Component {

    state = {
        columns: [],
        buttonPressed: false,
    }

    bubbleSort = (inputArr) => {
        let len = inputArr.length;
        for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            for (let j = 0; j < len; j++) {
                if (inputArr[j] > inputArr[j + 1]) {
                    let tmp = inputArr[j];
                    inputArr[j] = inputArr[j + 1];
                    inputArr[j + 1] = tmp;
                }
            }
        }
        return inputArr;
    };

    toggleOn = () =>{
        this.setState({
            columns: this.props.columns,
            buttonPressed: !this.state.buttonPressed,
        });
        let numbers = this.props.columns;
        this.bubbleSort(numbers);
    }

    render() {

        //riformulare queste tre righe di codice
        //sarebbe opportuno pensare ad un componente bar? 
        const numbers = this.props.columns;
        const bar = numbers.map((number) =>
            <div className="bar" style={{height: number+'px' }}>{number}</div>
        );

        return (
            <div>
                {numbers.length > 0 ?  
                <div>
                    <button className="sortButton" onClick={this.toggleOn}>Sort with Bubblesort</button>
                    <div className="chart">
                    {bar}
                    </div>
                </div>
                    : null      
                }
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Chart;
```

***Considerations***

1) the `this.props.columns` is an array filled of random numbers.

I saw something similar in this link, could you please give me a little help about some starting point ?

https://codepen.io/lonekorean/pen/bqjzqr

2) this is the repository where you will find all the components:

[github repository](http://%20https://github.com/AudereSemper/Visual-Bubblesort/tree/master/src/Components)

Comment: When you are doing the swap in your sort function, save the operation to an array, e.g. `const swaps = []; ... swaps.push({ i, j })`. When you want to animate, take the original unsorted array and start a timer using `setTimeout`. Every time the timer function is called, perform one swap from the array.

Comment: Thank you for the help :) i will update the post asap.